# Substitute integers and dots with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string and I need to substitute the numbers and dot with a star:

```
FOO_BAR_FOOBA_1_R:FOO_1.0
```

I tried the following but I just managed to substitute the last part, is there a way that I can do it with a single regex search? Or do I need to parse it twice?

Regex I tried is: `(\d.\d)`. That one catches the last part but not the beginning.

I am using PHP so below is the code that I have so far:

```
$re = '/(\d.\d)/';
$str = 'FOO_BAR_FOOBA_1_R:FOO_1.0';
$subst = '*';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result is".$result;
```

If I use `\d` I get all the integers but not the dot plus multiple stars.

Comment: Don't make people run your code to see results, post them. If you're just looking for dot's and digits and you aren't validating, just use `[.\d]+`

Comment: Please [edit] your post to state your exact expected output from your sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex:

```
(\d.\d)
```

is looking for `a number`, `any non new line character` (`.` is a special character in regex), and again `a number`. The only place that occurs in your string is at the end. For a demo of this see: https://regex101.com/r/vHef6Q/2/

You could use:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?
```

to find any numbers with an optional decimal part.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vHef6Q/1/

Be careful with `.`s in regexs. Also use [quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) if multiple values are allowed. `\d` is a single integer, for numbers greater than 9 you need a `+`. This also is the answer to why you get multiple starts when you just use `\d`.